# Circular UIImageView slow to change once updated to Xcode 8 beta and ios 10 Beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView inside a uitableview and before upgrading it seems fine but now it doesn't, take a second or two to go from square to circle as desired.

```
cell.logo.layer.cornerRadius = cell.companyLogo.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.logo.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

**Update**

```
PFUser *user = [object objectForKey:@"userTookPhoto"];
cell.logo.file = (PFFile *)user[@"profileImage"];
[cell.logo loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {
 cell.logo.layer.cornerRadius = cell.companyLogo.frame.size.width / 2;
 cell.logo.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }];
```

**Update 2**

I ended up doing this and it seems to be a lot more smoother. No more delay.

```
    cell.logo.file = (PFFile *)searchedObject[@"profileImage"];
   [cell.logo loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   //Code here to which needs to update the UI in the UI thread goes here
    cell.logo.layer.cornerRadius = cell.logo.frame.size.width / 2;
    cell.logo.clipsToBounds = YES;
            });
        }];
```

Comment: Sounds more like a threading problem. But you have not shown the necessary code to reproduce, so it's impossible to say. If you want help, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @matt ill add in more code that has to do with the UIImageView

Comment: I think i fixed it by adding the circular code inside the loadInBackground block.

Comment: @matt i was also wondering on when to use main thread for UIKit. Every time? Even when updating text or showing a spinner on the screen?

Comment: @matt sometimes it still is square before it gets to circular even when using the updated code.

Comment: @Prgmmr if the logo is an IBoutet then write a setter method for logo property and write the corner radius there . it will work

- (void)setImgView:(UIImageView *)logo{
    if (_logo == logo) {
        return;
    }
    _logo = logo;
    _logo.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    _logo.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    _logo.layer.cornerRadius = _logo.frame.size.width/2;
}

Comment: Exactly as I guessed, you have a threading problem. Do you understand what a thread is? Do you understand what "asynchronous" means? Do you understand what you're doing when you call `loadInBackground`? Do you understand that you _must never_ touch the interface (`cell.logo` and so on) except on the _main thread_?

Comment: Yeah i understand, i read up on it. So from what i read i should use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` for anything that has UI in front of it thats gonna be changing. Like setting a UIButton's text or UIImageViews image?